# Iterate over multiple collections with Concat and Foreach

Tags: c#

I have multiple arrays of the same type. I need to iterate over each to call a method on each element.

```
Foo[] array1;
Foo[] array2;
Foo[] array3;
```

I could do use multiple `foreach` loops, like this:

```
void PerformAction()
{
    foreach(var item in array1):
        item.DoAction();
    foreach(var item in array2):
        item.DoAction();
    foreach(var item in array3):
        item.DoAction();
}
```

Or a single `foreach` and `concat` each array together:

```
void PerformAction()
{
    foreach(var item in
        array1.Concat(
        array2.Concat(
        array3)))
    {
        item.DoAction();
    }
}
```

I think the `concat` style is a bit cleaner and requires less code, but is there an advantage of one method over the other?

Comment: Putting chained methods like that in a foreach statement is fairly unpalatable, i would create a variable, then foreach over that

Comment: `Concat` is ineffective than the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just move the `foreach` into a method and call it `x` amount of times?

```
public void PerformActions()
{
    PerformFooActions(array1);
    PerformFooActions(array2);
    PerformFooActions(array3);
}


private static void PerformFooActions(Foo[] foos)
{
    foreach(var foo in foos)
       foo.DoAction();
}
```

Using this approach it will be easy to convert the code into `async` behaviour in the future if that is ever needed. You also don't generate excess objects that need to be GC'd later on, like how you would using `Concat`.

Answer (score 1):

Three `foreach` statements will lead to code duplication. In some future, you will have more complex foreach body:

```
void PerformAction()
{
    foreach(var item in array1)
    {
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        item.DoAction();
    }
    foreach(var item in array2)
    {
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        item.DoAction();
    }
    foreach(var item in array3)
    {
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        item.DoAction();
    }
}
```

You can forget or missprint in any foreach body block.

So, extract your collections in one and make one foreach:

```
void PerformAction()
{
    var list = array1.Concat(array2).Concat(array3);

    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        // perfome some actions
        item.DoAction();
    }
}
```

Code looks cleaner.